# JPA Specification UUID field with Like operator

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to search UUID field in DB with LIKE operator but I'm failing, is there a way to do it in Specification?

my code:

```
private static final String LIKE = "%";

public static Specification<MyEntity> keyLike(final UUID key)
   {
      if (key != null)
         return (root, query, builder) -> builder.like(
                 builder.upper(root.get(MyEntity_.KEY)),
                 LIKE + key + LIKE);
      return (root, query, builder) -> builder.and();
   }
```

I tried converting it to stuff like `builder.upper(root.get(MyEntity_.KEY)).as(String.class)`
but it didn't work as well.

Comment: What do the values look like? Are they UUIDs as well? If so, do you realize that you'll get a _complete_ uuid, so `like(%uuid%)` would be practically the same as `like(uuid)`? Also what's the case of the DB data? Note that `UUID.toString()` will return a lower case string.

Comment: You are correct, it should be a String input.

Comment: Your code actually compares upper case to lower case which would never match: as I already commented `UUID.toString()` will cause a lower case string but you're using `builder.upper(...)` so the final condition will be like `UPPER('abc') LIKE '%abc%'` or `'ABC'  LIKE '%abc%'`). Try `builder.lower(...)` instead and if you want to be sure call `toLowerCase()` on the uuid string as well.